# I lost my data in IBM bluemix, it say that 'restart by ibmadmin'

Tags: ibm-cloud

I found out that my last 2 days data on my database was lost. It say that 'restart by ibmadmin' this data is very important to our project and we would like to have it back. please tell me what should i do to Recover it.

Comment: You should contact the IBM Bluemix support and ask for help

Comment: i already ask support. but I don't have any respond yet.

Comment: As far as I know, Bluemix has some backups strategies in place: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/162358/does-bluemix-backup-databases-and-if-so-how-would.html The only solution is to wait their reply then.

Comment: Which database service?

Comment: no it's sqlite database because cleardb is slowly for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This action occurring these days is regarding an announcement sent at the end of September to all customers via mail,  about an important upcoming change to the “stack” that underpins apps hosted on IBM Bluemix. All apps migration was needed, as informed.